# Changing Sharepoint render controls to use custom edit screen instead of Sharepoints edit scream- Custom Lookup Field

Tags: xml, sharepoint, custom-fields

How do you navigate to a different page when a user clicks an editable lookup field of a particulat list item in standard view instead of going to DispForm.aspx?

The problem:

We have a main web in Sharepoint which contains three other webs for each department of an organisation. Within this main web along with the other three webs is a list containing users.

To limit the control of the Sharepoint user we have created a custom edit form which needs to be accessible when the lookup value is clicked within the Sharepoint standard view of the list displaying the users in the main web.

(Sorry for the not so easy to understand explanation)

To cut a long story short I have edited the DisplayPattern in the FIELDS.XML file to read:

```
<RENDERPATTERN NAME="DISPLAYPATTERN">
<HTML><![CDATA[<TD><A HREF="XXXXXXXXXX.ASPX?ID=]]></HTML>
<COLUMN NAME="ID"/>
<HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
<FIELD/>
<HTML><![CDATA[</A><TD>]]></HTML>
</RENDERPATTERN>
```

This code works fine however it takes the current list item ID and not the LookUpID. How do I link to a custom form taking the LookUpID with me?

Thanks in advance